# Suggestion for a mongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a MongoDB schema

```
let fbUserSchema = new Schema({
  facebookId: {type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true},
  name: String,
  .
  .
  matched:[]
});
```

This is the way matched is stored in the database.

```
matched: [{
   charm: 234134134134, // it is a facebookId
   requester: 239846019346 // it is a facebookId
  },
  {
   charm: 576452234, // it is a facebookId
   requester: 58456363 // it is a facebookId
  },
   ....]
```

**`charm` and `requester` are `facebookId's` whose name's can be fetched from the same schema**

When I query for any users I get `matched []` matched is an array of objects.

```
fbUser.findOne({ 'facebookId': '34234234234'}, 'matched', (err, matched) => {
   console.log(matched);
 });
```

I want to query in a way that I can get the name of the `charm` and `requester` from the fbUserSchema. (I want to add `charmName`, `requesterName` in my result)

I want the result as

```
matched: [{
       charm: 234134134134, // it is a facebookId
       charmName: 'Alex',
       requester: 239846019346 // it is a facebookId
       requesterName: 'Bella',
      },
      {
       charm: 576452234, // it is a facebookId
       charmName: 'Julia',
       requester: 58456363 // it is a facebookId
       requesterName: 'John',
      },
     ....]
```

Can this be done efficiently in one MongoDB query?

Comment: fbUser.findOne({ 'facebookId': '34234234234'}, 'matched.charmName', 'matched.requesterName', (err, matched) => {
   console.log(matched);
 });

Comment: @Govna `matched.charmName` & `matched.requesterName` don't  exist i want to write query so I can add them in my result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there with some effort on your end :)

1. Use [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html)
2. Start with a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) of your `'facebookId': '34234234234'`
3. [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) `matched`
4. Do a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) on same collection to match first on `charm` id
5. Do a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) on same collection to match now on `requester` id
6. Now you have all the data you needed ... just do your grouping/projection to match your desired result.

Comment: can you pls give me a query ?